# Clips error : No objects of existing classes can satisfy is-a restriction in object pattern

Tags: class, artificial-intelligence, rule-engine, expert-system, clips

I am getting this error:

*[OBJRTBLD2] No objects of existing classes can satisfy is-a restriction in object pattern.*

when I run the follοwing rule:

```
(defrule update_input "Updateinput1" 
(object (is-a Shmeio) 
(timh ?eis1) 
(onoma "Eisodos 1"))
 => 
(printout t "htane: " ?eis1))
```

My code is the following:

```
(defclass Shmeio
(is-a USER)
(role abstract)
(single-slot timh
(type INTEGER)
;+   (cardinality 1 1)
(create-accessor read-write))
(single-slot onoma
(type STRING)
;+   (cardinality 1 1)
(create-accessor read-write))
(multislot input_at
(type INSTANCE)
(allowed-classes Eksartima)
(create-accessor read-write)))
(defclass Shmeio_Eisodou
(is-a Shmeio)
(role concrete))

(definstances facts
; ...............
([Kuklomata_Class10] of Shmeio_Eisodou
(input_at [Kuklomata_Class74])
(onoma "Eisodos 1")
(timh 21))
([Kuklomata_Class36] of Shmeio_Eisodou
(input_at [Kuklomata_Class76])
(onoma "Eisodos 2")
(timh 28))
([Kuklomata_Class45] of Shmeio_Eisodou
(input_at [Kuklomata_Class77])
(onoma "Eisodos 3")
(timh 13))
([Kuklomata_Class54] of Shmeio_Eisodou
(input_at [Kuklomata_Class77])
(onoma "Eisodos 4")
(timh 25))
```

Could anyone help me? Because I am stuck for like hours now.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes are non-reactive (you can't pattern match them) and this behavior is inherited by subclasses, so you have to explicitly enable this in the subclasses.

```
CLIPS> (defclass A (is-a USER) (role abstract))
CLIPS> (defclass A1 (is-a A) (role concrete))
CLIPS> (defclass A2 (is-a A) (role concrete))
CLIPS> (defrule A-match (object (is-a A)) =>)
[OBJRTBLD2] No objects of existing classes can satisfy is-a restriction in object pattern.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::A-match
   (object (is-a A)
CLIPS> (defclass B (is-a USER) (role abstract))
CLIPS> (defclass B1 (is-a B) (role concrete) (pattern-match reactive))
CLIPS> (defclass B2 (is-a B) (role concrete) (pattern-match reactive))
CLIPS> (defrule B-match (object (is-a B)) =>)
CLIPS>
```